# Javascript How do I deal with errors in Promise and makes the loop keepgoing and save the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to loop through the list of files and eventually save the array in my local drive.
However, the problem is once my code confronts any error, it stops running and doesn't save anything. What I want to achieve is to keep my loop running even if there is an error.

I'm still not fully confident with using Promise,

I'm going to fetch information using below code.

```
function getSongs(id, number) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        geniusClient.getArtistSongs(id, { "page": `${number}`, "per_page": "50" }, (error, songs) => {
            // console.log(error);
            // console.log(JSON.parse(songs).response.songs);
            if (error) {
                res('error', 'id is: ', id);
            } else {
                let songsArray = JSON.parse(songs)
                // console.log(songsArray.response.songs)
                res(songsArray.response.songs);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

and save the songs once I fetch all of them as below.

```
for (artist of resultArray) {
    console.log(artist.id);
    let songArray = await getSongs(artist.id, 1);
    artist.songs.push(...songArray)
}

// for (artist of resultArray) {
//     console.log(artist.id);
//     let songArray = await getSongs(artist.id, 2);
//     artist.songs.push(...songArray)
// }

roundnumber++;
console.log('round number is', roundnumber);

fs.writeFileSync('./songTest/test.json', JSON.stringify(resultArray))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested approach ...

Make sure that `getSongs()` returns a rejected Promise for as many error cases as possible.

```
function getSongs(id, number) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        // a synchronous error here will result in Promise rejection.
        geniusClient.getArtistSongs(id, { "page": `${number}`, "per_page": "50" }, (error, songs) => {
            try {
                if (error) {
                    throw error; // will be caught below and result in Promise rejection.
                } else {
                    // an (unexpected) error thrown here will also be caught below and result in Promise rejection.
                    let songsArray = JSON.parse(songs);
                    res(songsArray.response.songs);
                }
            } catch(error) {
                rej(error); // reject (expected/unexpected error)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

In the caller code, add a try/catch structure to handle errors.

```
for (let artist of resultArray) { 
//   ^^^ don't forget to declare variables
    try {
        let songArray = await getSongs(artist.id, 1);
        artist.songs.push(...songArray);
    } catch(error) {
        // catch any error arising from the try block,
        // including any arising from Promise rejection in getSongs().
        artist.songs.push({ 'error': error.message, 'id': artist.id }); // or whatever you want to represent an error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). From the MDN docs

> The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

Store the promises in an array, don't `await` them and pass that array to `Promise.allSettled`.
With this all your errors (if any) will be stored and returned to you in array at the end of the operation.